# Adjust google sheets script to retrieve text from all rows to add notes to cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to adjust this script in google sheets. The goal is to retrieve the text from a cell column B and add this as a comment to the cell in column A.

The script that is hardcoded for a specific cell (A2 + B2)

```
`function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A2");
  var sourceCell = sheet.getRange("B2");

  var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();

  targetCell.setNote(noteText);

}`
```

How do I change this into a dynamic script that retrieves the text in every row in column B and adds it to the comment of every cell of column A?

Comment: Use batch methods: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations then https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I've just finished the script.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is looking for a final solution:

```js
function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B5");
  range.clearNote();
  for (var x=1;x<5;x++) {
      range.getCell(x, 1).setNote(range.getCell(x, 2).getValue());
  }
}
```